# Accord du participe passé avec avoir, COD avant le verbe : règle désuète ?

Tags: accord, participe-passé

Je suis française, et normalement assez bonne en grammaire / orthographe, mais là j'ai un gros doute, un affreux doute même. C'est peut-être une question stupide mais... j'ai un doute affreux.

En principe, lorsqu'un verbe est conjugué au passé composé avec avoir, le participe passé s'accorde avec le COD si et seulement si celui-ci est placé avant le verbe : c'est ce qu'on m'a toujours appris. (Sauf divers cas retors avec les pronoms, notamment en orthographe réformée, bref, passons).

Dans le cas de base, on a "J'ai mang**é** une pomme" -> "La pomme que j'ai mang**ée**". On est d'accord ?

Sauf que de plus en plus souvent, je vois des gens qui omettent cet accord. Tout à l'heure, dans un article très sérieux : "L'étude que XXX a publié en avril 2013...". Moi, j'aurais écrit "publiée" parce que "étude" est féminin. Mais en fait, je vois ce type de phrases sans accord assez souvent, et du coup je me demandais : Est-ce que c'est vraiment / toujours, comme je le pense, une erreur, ou bien est-ce qu'il est maintenant possible d'omettre l'accord ?

Comment: *Être* ou *avoir* à revoir ? Question de titre...

Comment: Et bien cet accord est toujours dans les manuels scolaires et activement enseigné au collège, en tout cas :-) Par contre, puisque c'est "l'étude" et pas "la dissertation", c'est une des (j'espère rares) cas où je serais susceptible d'oublier de faire l'accord !

Comment: Qu'est-ce que vous voulez dire par *divers cas retors avec les pronoms* ? À ma connaissance, seul le *en* COD clitique déclenche l'accord par défaut Masculin-Singulier sans tenir compte du genre et du nombre du référent, pour les autres pronoms, je ne vois rien de spécial.

Answer (score 3):

Tout dépend de ce que vous appelez une règle de grammaire...

Cet accord est de moins en moins pratiqué à l'oral et cet usage se traduit par une présence réduite à l'écrit. Ce que vous appelez la règle d'accord semble se transformer en une possibilité d'accord.

Personne ne pourrait faire l'accord quand le COD n'est pas à la bonne place et ne pas ressentir un malaise linguistique<sup>1</sup> :

> Jean a *prise la pomme.
>   Jean a pris la pomme.

Mais la plupart des locuteurs, la plupart du temps, ne ressentent pas cette insécurité avec des constructions où l'accord est possible mais non fait :

> La pomme que Jean a <sup>%</sup>prise était pourrie.
>   La pomme que Jean a <sup>%</sup>pris était pourrie.

L'accord des participes passés conjugués avec être semblent se maintenir un peu mieux pour l'instant.

<sup>1</sup> Ici, l'étoile marque l'agrammaticalité, le pourcentage la variation entre locuteurs.

Answer (score 2):

Effectivement la règle (la norme) existe toujours. Mais comme le note [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accord_du_participe_pass%C3%A9_en_fran%C3%A7ais#Accord_entre_objet_et_qualificatif_conjugu.C3.A9) (en se basant semble-t-il sur Grevisse) :

> Dans le détail, la règle d'accord du participe passé conjugué avec avoir est passablement artificielle ; et la langue parlée la respecte très mal.

(Remarquez au passage la longueur de la page WIkipédia sur ce "simple point de grammaire".)

Une réflexion intéressante (datant de 2015) est faite par Wilmet ([ici](http://www.arllfb.be/ebibliotheque/communications/wilmet10012015.pdf)). Son argumentation est en trois points :

- **La norme** : c'est à dire les règles censées s'appliquer
- **L'usage** : c'est la partie la plus intéressante. De nombreux exemples d'erreurs (en particulier sur l'accord avec avoir) faites par des hommes politiques (Mitterand, Chirac, Sarkozy, ...), chanteurs (Brassens, Gainsbourg, Sardou, ...), écrivains et journalistes (le Monde, le Nouvel Obs, ...) sont examinés.

> Toutes les enquêtes le prouvent : jeunes 
>   et vieux, intellectuels et artistes, élèves et 
>   professeurs, experts et profanes, gens de 
>   la  rue  et  académiciens...,  personne  —  malgré  les  satisfécits  naïfs  que  se  décernent  les  «  champions  »  (sic)  des  concours  de  dictées  —  n’est  à  l’abri.

- **Le système** : c'est à dire comment on devrait concevoir l'accord en pratique, sans "formules magiques". Il s'agit principalement de l'opinion de Wilmet et d'autres sur la manière dont l'accord devrait être pratiqué et enseigné.

Answer (score 1):

Évidemment que cette règle de base de l'accord du participe passé est toujours d'actualité. Mais Malheureusement de plus en plus malmenée, et pas que par les moins érudits comme semblerait en attester ton exemple...

Answer (score 1):

Salut ! 
A ma connaissance, la règle continue d'exister. Je n'ai jamais vu « la pomme que j'ai mangé » Ça fait monter des larmes aux yeux. J'espère que j'ai bien répondu à le question que tu as posée. ;D 
Réponse aux lecteurs : Chacun a sa façon de s'exprimer. Heh heh, mais l'accord du verbe, selon l'Académie veut toujours : « La question que je vous ai posée. »
Maintenant un petit casse-tête pour faire sourire le plus grognon des lecteurs :     « Ce matin, sur l'avenue, j'ai acheté deux oublies au parfum à fraise. »  Alors, c'est quoi ce que j'ai acheté ce matin ?   La bonne réponse demain, sauf que le lecteur n'aura préalablement deviné ce que c'est qu'une oublie. (Petit conseil : Ce n'a pas rapport avec le redoutable oubliette d'antan. A demain !
En prime : je suis né bavard. Je commence avec une toute petite idée qui trotte dans la tête, et 
je finirai avec un roman.

Comment: Could you edit your teaser to make it understandable in French? I can't figure what is *le parfum à fraise* and what means the part following *La bonne réponse demain*...

Comment: Chuis preneur mais à la chantilly,svp!