# Accord avec un autre participe passé

Tags: accord, participe-passé

Je viens de lire [ce blog](https://medium.com/the-curious-storyteller/raconter-une-histoire-tragique-a223124ac3fa) : « Raconter une histoire tragique ».

Dans la troisième des phrases suivantes, notez les deux expressions en gras :

> Après avoir fini ce roman, j’ai décidé d’en savoir plus. J’ai d’abord été **étonnée** de trouver un écrivain aussi connu que David Foenkinos sur Twitter. **Je l’ai étée** encore plus quand après l’avoir interpelé, il m’a répondu en me donnant son adresse courriel.

Il me semble que ce « l' » a pour antécédent le participe passé (ou adjectif) « étonnée ».

1. L'accord de « étée » s'agirait-il d'une faute de frappe ?
2. Sinon, est-ce que le genre de « étonnée » détermine de quelque façon celui de « étée » ?
3. Où est-ce qu'il y a en jeu une autre règle que j'ignore ?

Merci !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C'est soit une faute de grammaire soit une faute de frappe. *Été*, participe passé du verbe *être* est **invariable**. Ceci pour la raison que c'est un verbe d'état et qu'il ne peut pas avoir de complément d'objet direct. Pour faire l'accord du participe passé avec *avoir* il faut que le verbe ait un complément d'objet direct. Voir [Accord du participe passé avec le COD et l'auxiliaire *avoir*](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/22161/358) et [Accord du participe passé avec avoir, COD avant le verbe : règle désuète?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/19106/358)
 Et aussi sur la Banque de dépannage linguistique, la [Liste de participes passés invariables](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2815).

> Le participe passé des verbes intransitifs (qui n’ont pas de complément d’objet), des verbes transitifs indirects (dont le complément d’objet est construit avec une préposition) et des verbes impersonnels (qui s’emploient avec le pronom neutre il) reste toujours invariable puisque ces verbes n’ont pas de complément direct avec lequel s’accorder.
>   On notera toutefois que certains verbes qui sont généralement employés de façon intransitive, transitive indirecte ou impersonnelle peuvent aussi être employés dans un sens où ils deviennent transitifs directs; le participe passé de ces verbes s’accorde alors avec le complément direct si ce dernier précède le verbe.

Comment: Ah, OK. Peux-tu développer ce point des participes invariables ? En effet, ce qui je n'ai pas mentionné c'est que j'ai trouvé ce blog même en cherchant « étée » après m'être demandé si « été » serait accordé, ce que j'ai cru ne jamais avoir vu. La présence de « étonnée » a confondu un peu cette supposition, mais je devine que selon cette règle, « l'enseignante que j'ái étée » serait fort incorrect. Et selon la banque de dépannage linguistique, « la valse que tu as valsée » serait aussi incorrect. Pourrais-tu en dire un peu plus, s'il te plaît ?

Comment: Ne t'en fais pas pour « valsé(e) », maintenant que j'ai compris la note sur les verbes normalement intransitifs qui peuvent néanmoins s'accorder lorqu'ils sont employés de façon transitive. Mais pourquoi  « été » serait-il invariable ? Je crois me souvenir que les verbes couples se comportent de façon très étrange en beaucoup de langues (dans la phrase « être enseignant » ce deuxième mot peut être analysé comme autre chose qu'un complément d'objet direct), mais existe-il une explication claire et précise pour ce manque d'accord ?

Comment: @LukeSawczak *Être* ne peut pas avoir de COD (il a des **attributs**, voir par ex. première remarque [ici](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compl%C3%A9ment_d%27objet_direct#Confusions)). Et comme il se conjugue avec *avoir* aux temps composés on applique la règle, aussi arbitraire et incompréhensible soit-elle.

Comment: Merci ! J'emploie les restes de mes connaissances de linguistique pour comprendre telle ou telle langue particulière mais avec divers degrés de succès. Ces notes sur la manière de laquelle le français traite les « verbs d'état » sont très utiles.

Comment: J'ai un question assez semblable que je hésite de demander une autre question: Est-ce un erreur: "Vous avez mentionné la pub que **j’ai faite** d’un laxatif"? Il existe dans le transcription et l'enregistrement audio de mon livre de grammaire

Comment: @user135711 *Vous avez mentionné la pub que j’ai faite d’un laxatif* : c'est l'accord du participe passé (*fait**e***) avec le complément d'objet direct (*que* → *la pub*) parce qu'il est placé avant le verbe. Voir réponses à [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/22161/358). Dans la phrase de Luke Sawczak ici il n'y a pas d'accord parce que *être* n'a (jamais) de complément d'objet direct

Answer (score 2):

Outre ce que Laure indique dans son post (ce « l' » n'est pas un vrai COD), je ne pense pas qu'on peut voir l'accord dans ce type de circonstance, parce que le pronom n'est pas féminin.

D'après ce que je comprends, on utilise le mot *le* où *l’* dans ce manière même pour un adjectif féminin:

> - Vous êtes **fatiguée** ?
> - Oui, je **le** suis.

On ne dirait pas « Oui, je **la** suis ».

Source: [Pronom neutre « le »](http://uoh.concordia.ca/pronoms/co/m/co/Le_pronom_neutre_le_-_B1.html)

> L'attribut est repris par le pronom *le,* qui est considéré ici comme un pronom neutre (sans indication de genre et de nombre) dans ce contexte.

Comment: Merci. L'idée de faire accorder un participe passé avec une autre chose qui n'est pas même un substantif me paraissait étrange. Ça rassure, de savoir qu'il n'existe aucune règle de ce type.