# Fonction syntaxique de « que » dans « il n'est plus l'homme qu'il était il y a trois ans »

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-relatifs

En français il y a les deux pronoms relatifs « qui » (sujet de la phrase relative) et « que » (object direct ou complément d'objet direct, COD). Dans la phrase « il n'est plus l'homme qu'il était » le pronom « qu' » se rapporte à « l'homme », donc à un attribut du sujet « il ». A l'intérieur de la subordonnée relative le pronom « qu' » est attribut du sujet « il », cette fois-ci dans la proposition relative:

> il + était + un autre homme + il y a trois ans =
>
> sujet + verbe + attribut du sujet + complément de temps
>
> (l'homme) + qu' + il + était ... =
>
> (antécédant) + attribut du sujet + sujet + verbe

Serait-il donc correct de dire que le pronom relatif « que » peut à part la fonction d'un COD exercer la fonction d' un attribut du sujet?

Comment: Perhaps, a similar German structure facilitates your understanding? « *Ohne meine Vergangenheit wäre ich nicht **der, der** ich jetzt bin.* » In a manner of speaking, you can see the word "l'homme" as the first "der" and the word "que" as the second "der".

Comment: Alors la phrase française signifie « Il n'est plus l'homme 'qui il' > qu'il (comme 's'il')  était avant son service militaire »?

Comment: Oh, this French phrase conveys the idea of: "Du hast dich seit ... wirklich verändert!". The "qu'il" is short for "que + il", not "qui + il", therein lies the confusion? And this relative pronoun "que" refers back to "l'homme" as its antecedent. He was some kind of person three years ago, but not anymore. You can see it this way: "*Il était très religieux il y a trois ans, mais ce n'est plus le même homme qu'auparavant*".

Comment: Ma question de départ était: Quel est le pronom relatif correct qui n'est ni sujet ni COD. En allemand, un attribut nominal du sujet est au nominatif, alors le pronom relativ est au nominatif aussi (er ist nicht mehr der, der er war). En français, le pronom relatif correspondant à l'allemand « der » est « qui » sauf - on le voit ici - dans les cas où il a la fonction d'un attribut du sujet. C'est une question d'interférence.

Answer (score 4):

Oui, comme le verbe « être » est ici une copule, tu as raison de supposer que ce « que » est un attribut du sujet (ou « [propriété](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copule_(linguistique)#En_fran%C3%A7ais) ») plutôt qu'un COD.

C'est-à-dire que dans la phrase non-inversée :

> Il était cet homme il y a trois ans

Ici aussi « cet homme » est un attribut du sujet.

Les phrases copulaires se comportent de façon singulière autre part aussi :

> Il est écrivain *(au lieu de « un écrivain »)*
>
> La femme qu'elle a été *(au lieu de « [étée](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/26187) »)*

Comment: Intéressant: Le manque de l'article indéfini souligne la qualité attributive. Dans ton premier exemple « écrivain » se comporte comme un adjectif. Pour ta deuxième exemple, je ne comprends pas tout à fait pourquoi l'accord ne se fait pas. Peut-être c'est dû au fait que le verbe « être » se conjugue avec « avoir » aux temps composés > accord seulement avec un COD antéposé, si je me rappelle correctement.

Comment: @RalfJoerres C'est ça. Dans les deux cas le COD serait antéposé. Mais si on compare «  La pomme qu'elle a mangé**e** » ... C'est que « manger » prend un COD mais « être » non. Ce qui démontre que « la femme » n'est pas un COD dans cette phrase-là.