# Accord de participe passé dans une phrase

Tags: accord, participe-passé

Dans la phrase : "J'ai trouvé une bonne recette et je l'ai essayé" que j'ai vu quelque part , le verbe Essayer ne devrait-il pas s'écrire "essayée" dans ce cas ? (Comme le COD est placé devant le verbe).
Merci pour votre aide.

Comment: Est-ce que ça répond à ta question ? [Accord du participe passé : « Les plats que j'ai cuisinés »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8386/accord-du-participe-pass%c3%a9-les-plats-que-jai-cuisin%c3%a9s) mais aussi: [Accord du participe passé avec avoir, COD avant le verbe : règle désuète ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/19106/accord-du-participe-pass%c3%a9-avec-avoir-cod-avant-le-verbe-r%c3%a8gle-d%c3%a9su%c3%a8te)

Comment: Je pense oui merci. Et le "et" ne pause aucune problème ?